# Is it possible to query Carbon retention levels from the Graphite URL API?

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

I need to be able to dynamically discover the configured retention levels in place for a metric or set of metrics from arbitrary Graphite/Carbon services. The existing Graphite API does not seem to expose this information.

Is there a sanctioned way of retrieving this information through the HTTP API short of hacking the Graphite source or otherwise exposing the carbon.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You'll be hacking the source to make this happen. Rudimentary Python knowledge would be essential.

1. Target metric- alpha.beta.charlie
2. Default metric storage- `/opt/graphite/storage/whisper`.
3. Metric file- `/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/alpha/beta/charlie.wsp`.
4. Along with the whisper package, comes a script- `bin/whisper-info.py`.
5. Do `/whisper-info.py /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/alpha/beta/charlie.wsp`.

You will get this-

```
maxRetention: 31536000
xFilesFactor: 0.0
aggregationMethod: sum
fileSize: 1261468

Archive 0
retention: 31536000
secondsPerPoint: 300
points: 105120
size: 1261440
offset: 28
```

You'll want part of this to be dispalyed dynamically via the webapp.
For that, declare a custom method in 
`graphite-web/webapp/graphite/render/functions.py`. To make it 'appear' in the webapp GUI, you'll have to make an entry in 
`graphite-web/webapp/content/js/composer_widgets.js`.

As far as the function is concerned, you can invoke `whisper.info(path)` method of the whisper library, or you can 'run' `bin/whisper-info.py` on the file, parse the output and display it as a graph.